# UITableViewAutomaticDimension for table view cell while keeping image aspect ratio

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, autolayout

So I use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for my table view and in the `viewDidLoad:` method I put this:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 190.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

the problem is I want to display image with various size and I want to maintain these Image aspect ratio. But, **if the** **image's `width` did not match the device `width`which is in points as opposed to size of the image which is in `pixel`** the imageview ends up being stretched. Sometimes `points` is worth 2 pixel or 3 pixel depending on the device (@2x or @3x).

Answer (score 1):

Points always correlate to pixels in the sense that the aspect ratio in points will be maintained in pixels so long as the pictures you have for 2x and 3x are the same aspect ratios. Automatic dimensions require that your constraints be set up in a fashion that allows the cell to grow according to the desired amount.

Give the image aspect fit or another aspect based growth if so desired and it will grow along with its container view. At this point it your responsibility to ensure the images in your assets are the proper aspect ratios.

The constraints you apply at this point are important in order for the cells to grow as desired. I would probably raise the images compression resistance and possibly lower its vertical content hugging. This only has to be done in the amount of 1 up or down normally, because it is just about its priority over the other things it is constrained to, unless you have toggles the other things amounts.

Without more information this is about as good of an answer as I have for you. The constraint setup is the most important factor of the cells growing properly, and the image will always maintain its aspect if you tell it to.